# Looking for an implementation of Two-Sample McNemar's Test in R

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying to perform a Two-sample McNemar's test on my data, but I was not able to find any R package implementing the method.

The Two-sample version of the test is described here : Feuer, Eric J., and Larry G. Kessler. “Test Statistic and Sample Size for a Two-Sample McNemar Test.” Biometrics, vol. 45, no. 2, 1989, pp. 629–36. JSTOR, https://doi.org/10.2307/2531505

I'm familiar with the simple McNemar's test function

```
mcnemar.test()
```

but it's not sufficient for what I'm trying to do.

Does anyone know a package implementing the test?

Comment: @RuiBarradas it's not what I'm trying to do. What you are refering is just an other way to do a one-sample McNemar's test.

Comment: See: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595012/compare-the-evolution-of-a-binary-variable-between-two-groups-of-a-panel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595012/compare-the-evolution-of-a-binary-variable-between-two-groups-of-a-panel)